# js function that takes html element as an argument

Tags: javascript, html

The text field should display in the list as a new item when the buttons are clicked
When I click the button the data of text are should be added in the list  as a new line. How to link a button to this function?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<ul id=parent></ul>
<input type="button" value="Add element to list" onclick="addList(parent)">
<input type="text" value="new id" placeholder="id" name="strCode"></p><p>
</head>
<body>
<form name="search">
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
var keyBox = document.search.strCode;
    function addList(parent) {
        var parent = document.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0];
        var li = document.createElement("li");
        parent.appendChild(li)
    }
    keyBox.addEventListener("strCode",addList)
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the event listener "strCode" ?

Comment: So read the textbox value and set the textContent with the value.

Comment: You have `<input>` and `<ul>` in the `<head>` of your document. You can't do that. All HTML code has to go in the `<body>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. HTML does not belong in the head
2. inline event handlers are not recommended. Here I use eventListener and add it to the button
3. your eventListener is not adding an event - I guess you thought the input field needed to listen and not the button
4. You have an ID=parent, use that instead of  `document.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0];`
5. You do not actually set the content of the LI you add
6. passing parent to the function and then using var parent will not work well

```
function addList(parent) {  
        var parent = document.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0];`
```

I believe you are looking for this kind of code -

**NOTE:**

- I moved the form elements inside the form, not that the form tag is needed at all
- I use the submit event and select the field - benefits, enter will update and autoselect the text after adding

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() { // on page load
  const strCode = document.getElementById("strCode"); // input field
  const listContainer = document.getElementById("parent"); // ul list

  document.getElementById("search").addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // stop submission
    const val = strCode.value; // value from input field
    const li = document.createElement("li");
    li.textContent = val;
    listContainer.appendChild(li)
    strCode.select(); // ready for next entry
  });
  strCode.select(); // ready for first entry
});
```

```html
<form id="search">
  <input type="submit" value="Add element to list" id="add" />
  <input type="text" value="new id" placeholder="id" name="strCode" id="strCode" />
</form>
<ul id="parent"></ul>
```

If you DO want to have different lists, you can have the target in a data attribute of the form and delegate from a container element

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() { // on page load
  document.getElementById("container").addEventListener("submit",function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // stop submission
    const tgt = e.target;
    const listContainer = document.getElementById(tgt.dataset.target); // shopping ot todo
    const strCode = tgt.querySelector("[name=strCode]");
    const val = strCode.value; // value from input field
    const li = document.createElement("li");
    li.textContent = val;
    listContainer.appendChild(li)
    strCode.select(); // ready for next entry
  });
  document.querySelector("[name=strCode]").select(); // ready for first entry in first form
});
```

```html
<div id="container">
<form id="shoppingForm" data-target="shopping">
  <input type="submit" value="Add element to shopping list"/>
  <input type="text" value="new shopping" placeholder="id" name="strCode"/>
</form>

Shopping: <ul id="shopping"></ul>

<form id="todoForm" data-target="todo">
  <input type="submit" value="Add element to TODO list"/>
  <input type="text" value="new todo" placeholder="id" name="strCode"/>
</form>

TODO:
<ul id="todo"></ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Couldn't the `button` `input` become a `submit` `input`, and the event listener listen to the `submit` event and use `event.preventDefault()` to prevent page reloading? That might be better since most browsers will accept the enter key as submitting the form.

Comment: @programmer Very good idea. I normally do just that. I have updated

Answer (score 0):

- Your `ul` and `input`s must be moved into the `body`.
- You must set the `textContent` of newly created `li`s if you want them to have any text.
- Why do you pass a `parent` parameter to `addList` if it is never used? (It is masked by the local `parent` variable.)
- The `form` is empty. You should probably put the `input`s in it.
- `strCode` is not the name of an event, so you can't use it like that with `addEventListener`. Since you already have an inline `onclick` event listener, what's that line for?

```
function addList() {
    var parent = document.getElementById('parent');
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.textContent = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[1].value;
    parent.appendChild(li)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple errors .. [see mplungjan answer],

Here is my code :

```js
function addList() {
   var text = document.getElementById("textVal").value;
     var li = document.createElement("li");
   var textnode = document.createTextNode(text);
     li.appendChild(textnode)
   document.getElementById("parent").appendChild(li)
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <input type="button" value="Add element to list" onclick="addList()">
    <input type="text" value="new id" placeholder="id" name="strCode" id="textVal">
    <ul id=parent></ul>
  <form name="search"></form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to place your input inside the form to access it by name.

Also, the event handler you added to the text input is invalid and should be removed since the button already calls the function.

```js
const
  form = document.forms.search,
  btn = form.querySelector('input[type="button"]'),
  keyBox = form.elements.strCode;

const addList = (listId) => {
  const
    targetList = document.getElementById(listId),
    listItem = document.createElement('li');
  listItem.textContent = keyBox.value;
  targetList.append(listItem);
  keyBox.value = '';
}
```

```html
<form name="search" onsubmit="return false;">
  <input type="button" value="Add element to list" onclick="addList('parent')">
  <input type="text" value="new id" placeholder="id" name="strCode">
</form>
<ul id="parent"></ul>
```

Comment: 1: Why confuse a noob that cannot even put elements inside a form with ES6 arrow functions 2: If you add advanced JS, why do you then have even more inline event handlers than before?

Comment: @mplungjan I kept the inline event handler because I wanted to show the minimal amount of changes required to get it functioning. I did not want to completely refactor. I just moved elements around in the DOM and fixed the list item function.